# Php timestamp database

Tags: php, mysqli, timestamp

I have a question about the data (articles) in my database.
I'm working on a script that create an output based on the date. 
Its means the last added article it the database must be on the top of a page. (still working on this).
I thought to do this with a timestamp (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is default value). 
The output on my screen is something like this: 2012-11-14 15:19:23.
My question now is: how do you cut this date into separated elements to be styled. 
I want to become a result where i can style the day, month, year with css.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT titel, datum from tblArtikels";
        if (!$result = $mysqli->query($sql))
            {
                throw new Exception('Fout in de query');
            }
        else
            {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    echo $row['titel'] . ' ' . $row['datum']. '<br/>';
                }
            }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a regular [timestamp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) you can use [date()](https://www.php.net/date%28%29) this to print your date out.  You need to use [time()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) to store the timestamp in your database

ex:

```
$day = date("l", $timestamp)
$month = date("M", $timestamp)
$year = data("Y", $timestamp)
```

here are the references:

[https://www.php.net/date()](https://www.php.net/date%28%29)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php

if you really want/need the time formatted a certain way you can use [strptime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) to specify a format when creating the timestamp.  The format is the same as in the link above.

Comment: Result of this query -> echo $row['titel'] . ' ' . date('d', $row['datum']) .'/'. date('m', $row['datum']) . '/' .date('Y', $row['datum']) . '<br/>';   

= 

01/01/1970

Comment: the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can do this. Either [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the variable in PHP or use the [DATE_FORMAT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) in the SQL query. Personally, I'd use the latter but the former will mean you can do more.

Edit:

Also, you want to use the ORDER BY datum to achieve the other part of your question:

SELECT titel, datum from tblArtikels order by datum

Comment: I used the date format within my sql statement ( echo $row['titel'] . ' ' . DATE_FORMAT($row['datum'],'%m-%d-%Y') . '<br/>'; ) but i have no output on my screen but also no errors, date is stored as a timestamp because that was the only way to get and auto date.